# Cannot figure out how to add a method to a string

Tags: javascript

My actual assignment is this:

> Add a new method to String called format which takes in some color, typeface (italic, bold, striked or none), fontsize, and whether to display in upper or lower case.
>
> Using your new formatting method, format the String "Jose lived in San Jose for many years." as blue, italic, size 12, and all uppercase.

Using the notes provided (along with sites I've found through google searching), the only thing I can come up with is this:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    string = string.fontcolor("Blue")
    string = string.italics()
    string = string.fontsize(12)
    string = string.toUpperCase()
    }
var string = "Jose lived in San Jose for many years."
document.write(string.format());
```

Comment: [MDN - Details of the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) might be helpful here. Also, [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 3):

Well first of all that function doesn't take any parameters, so how can you make it take colour, typeface, size or case???

Also, to get the string the function is called on, you use `this`. However, you can't change `this` so you have to use a temporary variable and `return` it at the end.

Something along these lines:

```
String.prototype.format = function(col,font,size,caps) {
    var str = this;
    // do stuff to str
    return str;
};
```

I shall leave it up to you to work out what to do to `str`.

Comment: functions don't _need_ params, you can always cycle through `arguments`

Comment: True, but to do that you need to refer to `arguments` somewhere ;)